# Expand a type containing an int pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

I've got a variadic template type looking like

```
template <int... Args> struct int_pack
{
    using type = int_pack<Args...>;
};
```

I now want to call a function `Func` with an int pack (e.g. `int_pack<0, 1, 2>`) so that I'm calling `Func` with `Func(0, 1, 2)` instead of `Func(int_pack<0, 1, 2>{})`.

**Edit 1:** I can't/don't really want to edit `Func` as I don't know it. The context here is, that I have another function (e.g. `Wrap`):

```
template <typename Func, int N> auto Wrap(Func func)
{
    return func(?int_pack<N>?);
}
```

(instead of `?int_pack<N>?` I want to expand the pack)

**Edit 2/Motivation:** I currently have a function `WrapSingle`:

```
template <typename Func, typename... Indices> auto WrapSingle(Func func, Indices... indices)
{
    return func(Get(indices)...);
}
```

with `double Get(int)` being just another function.

Now instead of `WrapSingle(func, 0, 1, 2)` I want to write `Wrap<2>(func)`/`Wrap(func, 2)` where the `2` expands to `0, 1, 2` via the `int_pack`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <typename Func, int... Args N> 
auto Wrap(Func func, int_pack<Args...>)
{
    return func(Get(Args)...);
}

template <typename Func, int N> 
auto Wrap(Func func)
{
    return Wrap(std::move(func), make_int_pack<N>());
}
```

`make_int_pack` is essentially [`std::make_integer_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence). Looks like you are using C++14 anyway, so just use that and `std::integer_sequence` instead of your custom type. If you are stuck with C++11, there are plenty of implementations on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Just write an overload that takes an `int_pack` and forwards along its template arguments:

```
template <int... Args>
void Func(int_pack<Args... > ) {
    Func(Args...);
}
```

Comment: I forgot that I basically wan't to leave `Func` unchanged. See my edit

Comment: @Uroc327 perhaps you didn't notice, but *your* `Func` *wasn't* changed. Hence the "overload" part of this answer.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, but I also do not know it. So overloading `Func` is not very generic and I would need to overload every function I want to pass to `Wrap`.

Comment: @Uroc327 Use the same technique, but on `Wrap` instead.